# OpenCV installation help?

Tags: opencv, installation, libraries, codeblocks

I am on  Mac OS X Snow Leopard, and I am trying to get OpenCV to work with CodeBlocks. I downloaded the source files for OpenCV 2.3, and then downloaded the latest version of Cmake. The direct source file contains a folder "include" which has two folders in it labeled OpenCV and OpenCV 2. However after I use Cmake on the source files, the two "OpenCV" and OpenCV 2" folders are gone. Anyone know why this is happening and how to fix it? Instead of the folders all I have now is a CmakeFiles Folder, MakeFile and cmake_install.cmake

Thank You

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After you download the source files, go into the `opencv` folder that's inside the folder you created and execute these commands:

```
sudo cmake -G "Unix Makefiles" .
sudo make -j8
sudo make install
```

Don't try to do this from the `include` folder. That's one level too deep. You want to do it from the folder that contains the `include` folder.

Terminal is in Applications/Utilities. That's how you get to the Unix command line. To get into your `opencv` folder, run Terminal and type "cd ". (That's `cd` followed by a space.) Then drag your `opencv` folder from a Finder window onto the Terminal window. This will append the folder name to the command line. Then press Return and you'll be in that folder. Then you can enter the commands above.

If you want to use ccmake instead of cmake, just replace "cmake" with "ccmake" in the first command.

Comment: Thanks but Im really new to the whole thing- I don't know how to go into a folder through terminal.
And secondly I can't just make them, because I need to use the Cmake GUI to specify important options.

Thank You

Comment: I'll expand my answer to add what to do in Terminal

Comment: In-source build is strongly not recommended for OpenCV. It's better to create separate `build` folder and run cmake in that folder. Also I'm afraid that building with `sudo` is not a good idea.

Comment: @Andrey I'm going by the instructions on the [the OpenCV Wiki](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/Mac_OS_X_OpenCV_Port). If you know of a better way, please add it to the Wiki. Until then, what can we do but assume that the instructions at opencv.willowgarage.com are the current best practice?

Comment: thanks ssteve :)
just wondering but how would i make the source and build files in different folders? Cause putting them both together feels really disorganized to me :)

Comment: oh and also i tried out the method above and it seemed to be working properly. but when i use sudo make -j8 it works upto 22 percent and the becomes EXTREMELY slow. I mean it took me an hour and a half to go from 22-30 percent. And during this time, my whole computer becomes REALLY slow, and applications become too slow to use.
Any help with this? Thanks

Comment: I'm not sure what else to suggest. That process worked fine for me under OS X 10.6.8, Andrey's recommendations notwithstanding. I don't remember how long it took to compile everything--less than an hour and a half, though. I have 8Gb RAM in a 2.8GHz Core 2 Duo MacBook Pro.

Comment: allright thanks 
just one more thing, after you do the commands, do you have 2 folders in your include folder?

Comment: the folders names are opencv and opencv 2

Comment: @SSteve unfortunately OpenCV documentation is very disjoined. And some parts often contain untested or even incorrect info. Commands from wiki should work correct for the clean first-time build but can cause problems if you are going to work with OpenCV sources. I don't want to update wiki without trying to execute commands but I have no Mac on hands to run an experiment.

Comment: @Farhad out of source build is very simple with cmake - you just need to create a new folder and run cmake from that folder:
`mkdir build && cd build && cmake ..` instead of `cmake .`
About 2 include folders - by default headers for OpenCV 2.x are distributed by the OpenCV modules and are copied to the 2 include folders only when you run `make install` command.

Comment: Yes, after building there are 2 folders in my include folder: opencv and opencv2. The entire build took less than 10 minutes. @Andrey I updated the Wiki to create a separate build directory per your instructions. I downloaded a fresh copy of the source and tested the process and it works.

Comment: Thank You :) I finally got it too work after spending a whole day trouble shooting 
turns out ffmpeg was causing problems so i built it without ffmpeg